# flutter video player play Aes Encryption Video

Tags: flutter

I am creating a flutter app where in I want to play an encrypted video. The requirement is that the encrypted video first is decrypted as a stream, and then this stream would be played in a video player.

Is there a video player SDK available in Flutter that handles this use case?